# Notepad++ find and exclude a character

Tags: regex, search, replace, find, notepad++

I have a CSV file with lines like this:

- Option,100,1; 3; 4; 2,,
- Option,100,Intérprete,,

I tried the regexp (^Option,.+,.+[^;].+,,) to find lines above, but excluding
the lines with ";" characters in third comma separate value.
My regexp is not working, is not excluding the lines I don't want to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the dot that is too permissive, use negated character classes like that:

```
(^Option,[^,]+,[^,;]+,,)
```

`[^,]` means *all characters except `,`*

Note: the parenthesis are probably not useful.

Comment: Thank you Casimir,  I am a step further, just one more thing, how can I make more specific to the pattern "1; 3; 4; 2", the number before the the ";" will vary. I ask because I just found that have lines like the following that I need to find: Option,100,Int&eacute;rprete,,
Many thanks,

Comment: @user3922473: You can replace `[^,;]+` with `(?:[^,;]|(?<!\d);)+`. An other way consists to skip html entities: `(?>[^,;&]+|&[^,;]+;|&)+`